# Store value after loop has been terminated

Tags: python, while-loop, raw-input

Suggestions on how to store the last value entered by a user i.e. when raw_input() returns an empty string ('') (Enter was pressed). For e.g. if the user value has 50. How can this be stored in the variable "dollar"

This is after a loop has been terminated

```
while dollar < 55 or  num_rate > 55: 
    print dollar, "is outside the permitted range, try again"
    dollar = float(raw_input("Enter value between 55 and 65: "))
```

Comment: `dollar` will still have the entered value after the loop completes.  Can you add more detail to show what you want to happen?

Answer (score 1):

You should handle `ValueError` errors gracefully in case user may hit <kbd>enter</kbd> without actually typing anything.

Assuming `dollar` is already initialized somewhere above the `while` block:

```
while num_rate > 55.0:
    try:
        dollar = float(raw_input("Enter value between 55 and 65: "))
    except ValueError:
        break
    else:
        if 55.0 < dollar < 65.0:
            break

        print dollar, " is outside the permitted range, try again"

print "last value of dollar: ", dollar
```